# py2exe ImportError: No module named cssselect

Tags: py2exe, importerror

I used `pyquery` in my App, when I run main.exe in the dist directory, the error occures:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "f2.pyo", line 4, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "pyquery\__init__.pyo", line 11, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "pyquery\pyquery.pyo", line 6, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
  File "pyquery\cssselectpatch.pyo", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cssselect
```

But as you can see, pyquery uses cssselectpatch not cssselect, how to fix it?

Comment: Please post your `setup.py`. `cssselectpatch` tries to import `cssselect` but cannot find it.

Comment: #-*-coding: UTF-8-*-
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

# Powered by ***
INCLUDES = []
options = {"py2exe" :
           {"compressed" : 1,"optimize" : 2,  
      "bundle_files" : 2,  
      "includes" : ["pyquery"],  
      "dll_excludes": [ "MSVCP90.dll", "mswsock.dll", "powrprof.dll","w9xpopen.exe"] }}  
setup(
     options = options, 
     description = "鬼谷子",  
     zipfile=None,
     console=[{"script": "main.py"}],
     )

Comment: Don't post it as a comment, use the edit button on the bottom left of your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you can run your program without `py2exe`, i.e. as a Python script with `python main.py`.
2. Use `py2exe`.
3. If you still get an error add `import cssselect` to `main.py` and try to use `py2exe` again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with cssselect, but before that
it was with html5lib, what I did to solve the problem was to install 
html5lib manually ex: python setup.py install and a directory was created
and the error regarding html5lib didn't show, then came the error with cssselect, 
I did the same thing but the installer creates a egg file not a directory
with all the structure inside, because py2exe only imports the libs with the 
directory structure the binary doesn't work.

To solve the problem we have to install cssselect in the tree structure:
download cssselect from github, decompress and copy the dir **cssselect** that's inside **cssselect-master**
to your python **site-packages**.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (similarity can apply to Linux) you can just install it and the installer will find your local installed python to add cssselect module in. the source info taken from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect.

Here is how:

pip install cssselect

Now your python will NOT complain for csselect module missing.

If you do not have pip command then install pip.

Tested, Works!